# Edit question from Triage review

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-queues, edits, triage

When reviewing in the Triage queue, I often see malformatted questions. Most of the time it's easy to improve by simply putting the code in the correct environment.

However, editing the question is not possible from within the Triage review. Instead, I feel tempted to click "Should be improved". Normally, I then go the question directly and edit the question.

I can think of two shortcomings with this approach:

- After my edit, the question may be regarded as "Looks OK" by other reviewers, but as I clicked "Should be improved", a fourth review became necessary. That's inefficient.
- After having edited, the question is not immediately improved. First someone has to accept the edit. In the meantime, another reviewer may review the question while seeing that it's not acceptable. She then also wants to edit it and after her edit, she would learn that another edit is pending. That's inefficient as well.

So what's the right way to handle edits for question that are actually in the Triage queue? If it's already a known shortcoming, why not doing something about it? For example, reviewers should know when an edit is pending, and ideally be able to edit the question right from the Triage review.

Comment: The problem is not with the triage queue, but you misunderstanding what it's for: It's only for triage, that means fast sorting into the three groups 1. Should be answered as-is 2. Needs editing by the community 3. Cannot be salvaged by community. When you get full edit rights at 2K, you can go to the H&I queue to do editing of triaged questions ...

Comment: I edit stuff in triage too, so you're not alone :-)

Comment: I'd like to add another issue: People who clicks **Requires editing** *know* how editing can improve it, but not necessarily other people in the Help queue. So allowing editing from T grants this advanges: Whoever know how to edit it, do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of Triage is to... Triage questions. Predict their likely outcome, and direct them in the direction most appropriate for that outcome. It is paramount that reviews be completed *quickly* so that this information may be of benefit to others - once done, actual work (answering, editing, closing) may be performed.

Now, that doesn't stop *you* from taking further action on a post in Triage that catches your eye; **if you're moved to edit (or answer) a post that you find via Triage, by all means do so!** Just review first, and then step out of the queue to perform these additional actions.

As to which option you choose in Triage... It's not as crucial as you suspect.

- **Should be Improved:** Chances are, the post will already be triaged before you complete your edit; if you say it should be improved *and then improve it*, your edit will be seen in due time and applied - all is right with the world. If perchance you are called away and unable to complete your edit then the question is still categorized properly and will be edited by yourself or others at some later date (or not); again, all is in its place.
- **Looks OK:** if the edit you plan to make would be beneficial but not critical to the success of the question, then it is perfectly fine to say that the question is acceptable as it stands. Again, it will be waiting for you or others who care to edit.

The most important factor here is that you do not dally: make a decision quickly and give others a chance to review. Once you've done this, you can take as much time as is needed to edit, whereas allowing editing *within* this queue would impose a significant delay. It is for this reason that I must decline this request.