# Replace "Requires Editing" with "Edit" in Triage if the reviewer has Editing Privileges

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

I think that the "Requires Editing" button is only for reviewers who doesn't have the Editing Privileges, so use that option to put the post into another queue for users who have more than 2k rep to edit and improve.

[image: The "Requires Editing" button]

But since I have more than 2k rep, I can just edit it instead of ask other reviewers. I think we can just replace that button with a "Edit" button. So we can just edit the post, instead of *open the post's link; edited; make the Triage item as "Looks OK"*.

[image: Replaced it with "Edit"]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293876/edit-question-from-triage-review, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289801/i-feel-like-im-abusing-the-triage-queue-editing-questions-as-i-go-through, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295284/bad-practice-to-edit-questions-in-triage-queue

Comment: If you want to edit posts, why are you in the triage queue? Or are you asking for a way to remove yourself from the queue in a single click when you've decided that you're done triaging and want to edit something?

Comment: @BoltClock: Okay...before I close my question as dupe: "Why do we need edit the question in another queue, rather than just edit it in the triage queue?" Or in other words, "why we shouldn't edit posts in the triage queue?"

Comment: Again, I ask, if you're interested in doing anything other than triaging why are you in the triage queue? If you want to fix problems with posts, there are a variety of other review queues that you can use.

Comment: I guess the idea is that Triage seeks to quickly sort through the problematic posts, not actually fix them. Like a field medic who is triaging patients. Even if it's a simple fix, you don't actually treat the patient. That said, I'm not really sure what the point of having this queue on Stack Overflow is... But I'm too lazy to do research on Meta to see if there are statistics telling us that it is making a difference.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, fine. Fair enough, Triage is Triage is Triage.

Comment: The problem with using the "Requires editing" button is that, in my experience, the H&I queue is terrible at editing. Blatant errors such as code spilling outside of a code block are often left unedited. Sending anything more subtle to the H&I, such as invisible HTML or code in comments, is completely pointless. An alternative to stepping outside of the Triage queue to perform the edit, is to revisit your own review history and apply the edits at a later time.